# What's the name of the intro song in The Day Naruto Became Hokage?

Tags: naruto, theme-song

I would like to know the name of the intro song (when the lineage of Hokage is shown) in The Day Naruto Became Hokage. This song is also used many times in Shippuden. For example, Episode 234 (minute 18). I can't seem to find it anywhere on the internet or any of the released OSTs.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

It is called Memories

You can find it here : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hrfWJKMcFCM